# Copy range within a for next structure

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy a range from one sheet to another in a looping process. Right now this is the code I have

```
For i = 4 To Worksheets.Count
Worksheets(i).Activate
Sheets("DATA").Range(Cells(i - 2, 2), Cells(i - 2, 6)).Copy
ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
```

I've tried rewriting the code in several different ways but it always comes up with an error in the third line. I've checked the values of "i" and they are correct.

Any ideas of what might I be doing wrong?

Comment: Can you add the error message you're seeing to the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is trying to construct a range using cells from another worksheet (the default [ActiveSheet property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822753.aspx)).

```
Worksheets(i).Activate
Sheets("DATA").Range(Cells(i - 2, 2), Cells(i - 2, 6)).Copy
```

It should be closer to,

```
Worksheets(i).Activate
Sheets("DATA").Range(Sheets("DATA").Cells(i - 2, 2), Sheets("DATA").Cells(i - 2, 6)).Copy
```